# How to change variable in commnd prompt numerically

Tags: date, cmd, variable-assignment

I have used system date from %date% using this code
    set d=20%date:~6,2%%date:~0,2%
Its output is say 201309
How can I get the same for date of 30 days back(so I want 201308)? like is there any operation like addition/substraction for dates? I tried 
    set /a "date2=%date%-30"
But it gives error :"Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17),
hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021)." as cmd asumes a value is hexadecimal if it starts with 0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dos batch programming: howto get and display yesterday date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954359/dos-batch-programming-howto-get-and-display-yesterday-date)

Answer (score 0):

Using this batch file you should get what you need:

The routines can do some extra date math - the batch file is after the first 9 lines and can be self contained.

```
@echo off
call datebatch today -30
set "var=%day:0,6%"
echo "%var%"
pause
goto :eof
:datebatch
:: Date foward & backward
@echo off
if "%~2"=="" (
echo to get todays date use         call "%~n0" today 0
echo to get yesterdays date use     call "%~n0" today -1
echo to get 25 days before 19441213 call "%~n0" 1944/12/13 -25
echo to get 1250 days in the future call "%~n0" today 1250
echo.
echo Add a third parameter if you want a separator in the date string
echo EG: for this format YYYY-MM-DD using today's date
echo     call "%~n0" today 0 -
echo.
pause
goto :EOF)

set date1=%1
set qty=%2
set separator=%~3
if /i "%date1%" EQU "TODAY" (set date1=now) else (set date1="%date1%")
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%qty%,%date1%)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+month(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set result=%%a
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
endlocal& set "YY=%result:~0,4%"&set "MM=%result:~4,2%"&set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "day=%YY%%separator%%MM%%separator%%DD%"
echo %%day%% is set to "%day%" (without the quotes)
echo %%YY%% is set to %YY%
echo %%MM%% is set to %MM%
echo %%DD%% is set to %DD%
```