# Batch scripts to copy files

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

I need help to create a batch file to copy files with specifc date and version. And my date will be as of yesterday. Example file name:`- abcde-20150811-v1.csv`

I have tried `xcopy` with `/d:08-11-2015` ( it picks all files with date modified as `08-11-2015 MM-DD-YYYY`)

Is there a way that my batch automatically picks the date and gets changed everyday.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mean copy files that has file name contains yesterday's date? Or simply copy yesterday modified files?

Comment: Copy files that has filename containing yesterdays date

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at this: [How to get and display yesterday date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954359/dos-batch-programming-howto-get-and-display-yesterday-date)

If I were you, I'd go with a scripting language like Perl, or use PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code, haven't tried it yet though.

```
@echo off

set completepath=c:\users\microsoft\desktop\source
set destination=c:\users\microsoft\desktop\destination

set /a yesterday=%date:~4,2% - 1
set yesterday_date=%date:~10,2%%date:~7,2%%yesterday%

FOR /R %completepath% %%G IN (*.csv) DO call :process "%%~dpG" "%%~nG"
pause >nul

:process
SET %name%=%~2
SET chkname=%name:*%yesterday_date%=?%
IF "%chkname:~0,1%"=="?" (
    xcopy %~1 %destination% /y 
)
```

You may change the `completepath` and the `destination` variable.