# How to upload yesterday file to SFTP using .bat file and WinSCP?

Tags: batch-file, file-upload, ftp, sftp, winscp

This is my code getting the server date yesterday.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set /A "DD=(%dt:~6,2%)-1"
set datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%
set RunDate=%datestamp%
```

---

However, I'm trying to add this condition in this syntax:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /console ^
  /command "open sftp://Username:Password]@port" "cd /Dir" "put Dir\.CSV file" pause exit
```

---

So it will be:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com /console /command 
open sftp://USER:PASS]@IP
cd Dir
@echo off
setlocal
del Dir\Script.txt
echo User>>Dir\Script.txt
echo Pass>>Dir\Script.txt
echo passive>>Dir\Script.txt
echo prompt>>Dir\Script.txt
echo cd Dir>>Dir\Script.txt
echo binary>>Dir\Script.txt 

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do 
set 
"dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set /A "DD=
(%dt:~6,2%)-1"
set datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%
set RunDate=%datestamp%
echo %RunDate%
echo put Dir_%RunDate%.csv>>Dir\Script.txt

echo close>>Dir\Script.txt


pause 
exit  /b
```

---

I'm trying to add the variable: `%RunDate%` to any `.csv` file (Yesterday date with format) to upload it to the SFTP.

Comment: It's not clear, what you want to do. Do you want to upload all `.csv` files which file names include the current date? I.e. `aaa20171016.csv`, `bbb20171016.csv`, etc?

Comment: Hi Martin, 

Thanks for the reply. I would like to upload one file that has a value of yesterday date. Example filename:  Data_Country_20171015.csv.

Comment: So there's always only one file with the yesterday date?

Answer (score 1):

First, your code to calculate yesterday date is not reliable. It won't work on the 1st of a month. For example on the October 1st, it will produce invalid date `20171000`, instead of the correct `20170930`.

---

You can actually [use WinSCP itself to calculate the yesterday date](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_formatting_timestamp_batch_file#relative) way more easily and mainly reliably:

```
set TIMESTAMP_FORMAT=yyyymmdd
set TIMESTAMP_RELATIVE=-1D

for /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F in (
  `winscp.com /command "echo %%TIMESTAMP%TIMESTAMP_RELATIVE%#%TIMESTAMP_FORMAT%%%" "exit"`
) do set TIMESTAMP=%%F

echo %TIMESTAMP%
```

---

Though even that is actually not necessary, as WinSCP can upload yesterdays files on its own (using the same [`%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp) as shown above):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@example.com/" ^
    "cd /remote/path" ^
    "put *%%TIMESTAMP-1D#yyyymmdd%%*.csv" ^
    "exit"
```

This is partially based on WinSCP article [Uploading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_most_recent_file#alternatives).

---

Side notes:

- WinSCP does not have any `pause` command.
- You may need to add [`-hostkey` switch to the `open` command to make the script portable](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#hostkey).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggestion, however I failed to integrate it to my codes.

This link help me to properly declare a yesterday date as you advise to have a reliable calculation: [How to get and display yesterday date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954359/how-to-get-and-display-yesterday-date/18609647#18609647).

What did I implement is that the value of %AWSDT% is being replaced by %RunDate%